# Issue in recording script using Jmeter in Android

Tags: jmeter, automated-tests

In JMeter, use Templates > Recording
Unfold Workbench > HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder and start recorder
A certificate authority file is generated in jmeter/bin folder called ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt
Install it in Android
Connected my device in to desktop by advance setting in wifi 
But its not recording my action in desktop.............
How to find whether my device is connected but desktop?

Comment: Hello @Mohana Priya, welcome to StackOverflow! We'd love to help, but your question gives us very little information. Please consider reading how to make a [minimal, verifiable, and complete question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and editing your question accordingly.

Comment: Please add a little more details about what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

First use JMeter Recording Template
Then start JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), it will generate in jmeter/bin folder, a file called  `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` . 
Copy file to your android device and install it as CA Certificate.
See [How do I install a user certificate?](https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/articles/1841102-installing-burp-s-ca-certificate-in-an-android-device) thread for more details.

The certificate has limited life time (defaults to 7 days) but you can extend it by setting in user.properties

> proxy.cert.validity=Number of days

Now the problem you'll face in Android >= 7.0 is that applications only use by default System installed Certificates.

So you'll need to ask developper of application to modify the APK, see why [here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config).

Edit manifest and add :

> android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"

You'll get:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest ... >
     <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
                ... >
    ...
     </application>
 </manifest>
```

Then add in res/xml/network_security_config.xml this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <network-security-config>  
       <base-config>  
             <trust-anchors>  
                 <!-- Trust preinstalled CAs -->  
                 <certificates src="system" />  
                 <!-- Additionally trust user added CAs -->  
                 <certificates src="user" />  
            </trust-anchors>  
       </base-config>  
 </network-security-config>
```

Note that this is needed whatever tool you use (Neoload, LoadRunner, ...)

For full details read:

- https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/how-to-record-android-application-using-https-traffic-jmeter/